# Show that a linear functional does not belong to a dual space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

So I have the following statement to prove

> Let $L:C\:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ be a linear functional defined by
>   $$ Lf=f(0)$$
>   Show that $L\notin(C[0,1],||\cdot||_2)^*$, where $||\cdot||_2$ is the usual 2-norm.

This functional is definitely linear, so I guess I need to show that it is not continuous, I understand that if I show that it is not continuous at one point, then it's not continuous anywhere.

But suppose I take $f=0\in C\:[0,1]$, then if I get $\varepsilon>0$ by taking $\delta=\epsilon$ I obtain
$$ ||0||_2<\delta \: \Rightarrow\: |0|<\epsilon 
$$
So it seems that $L$ is in this dual space, where is my reasoning wrong and what would be the correct way of proving this statement?

Comment: Problems are solved, statements are proved.

Comment: Just a comment about terminology: you're trying to show that $L$ isn't in the *continuous* dual space. $L$ *does*, however, belong to the algebraic dual space, which is just the set of all (possibly unbounded) linear functionals.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong what is the proper notation for the continuous dual space?

Comment: The notation you used is fine. Almost all textbooks on analysis concern themselves only with the continuous dual space, for obvious reasons. I just was pointing out something that you might want to specify in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_n(x):=(1-n x)^+:=\max\{1-nx,0\}$. These $f_n$ are continuous, and $L(f_n)=1$ for all $n\geq 1$. From
$$\|f_n\|_2^2=\int_0^{1/n}(1-2n x+ n^2 x^2)\ dx={1\over 3n}$$
it follows that $${L(f_n)\over \|f_n\|_2}=\sqrt{3n}\to\infty\qquad(n\to\infty)\ .$$
This shows that there is no $C>0$ with
$$|L(f)|\leq C\|f\|_2\qquad \forall f\in C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)\ .$$
Therefore $L$ is not continuous with respect to the $L^2$-norm on $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$.

Comment: When finding the norm, why do you integrate with $1/n$ as upper bound?

Comment: @Jimmy R: By definition $a^+$ is $=a$ if $a\geq0$ and $=0$ if $a<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g_n$ such that $f_n(0)=1$, $g_n(n^{-1})=0$, $g_n(1)=0$ and $f_n$ is piecewise linear. Then take $f_n:=\sqrt{g_n}$^to see that $L$ is norm continuous if we endow $C[0,1]$ with the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: I didn't get this, isn't $L^2$ a norm for sequences?

Comment: I meant the norm on the space of continuous functions given by $||f||^2=\int_0^1f(t)^2dt$.

Comment: It's exactly what I wrote, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you would have to check the condition for all $f \in C[0,1]$ with $\|f\|_2 < \delta$, not just $f=0$.

Comment: For a linear functional continuity at a point implies continuity and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't check continuity at the single point 0, because he only showed that one point of his $\delta$-neighbourhood is mapped to the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $f(0)$, which is trivial.